# javascript: get index of object from dictonary key

Tags: javascript, dictionary

my data array

```
data : [
  {
    "name": "Autauga, AL",
    "value": 5.6
  },
  {
    "name": "Baldwin, AL",
    "value": 5.3
  },...
]
```

How can I retrieve the index of an array object if I just have the name "Autauga, AL"?
I am aware of the brute force loops. is there a better way?

Comment: What makes loops "brute force"?

Comment: Without building some other "index" of your data so you can directly lookup by name, there is no other way besides looping through the array to find the matching object.

Comment: Hm is the data ordered by chance lexicographically with regards to the name? If not you can build up your algorithm on that.

Answer (score 2):

In ECMAScript 5.1+, you can use the `Array#filter` method to get the actual object:

```
data.filter(function(item){return item.name == 'Autauga, AL'})[0]
```

That doesn't get you the index, though.  You could do this:

```
data.map(function(item,index){
  return [item, index]
}).filter(function(a){
  return a[0].name == 'Autauga, AL'
})[0][1]
```

Those methods still wind up using loops under the covers, but I guess they look cooler..

For efficient access, you could build an index for the target field:

```
var dataIndexByName = {}, i, len;
for (i=0, len=data.length; i<len; ++i) {
   dataIndexByName[data[i].name] = i
}
```

After which you can just look for `dataIndexByName['Autauga, AL']`.  That also has the advantage of working in older implementations.  It gets a bit more complicated if a given name might show up more than once in the original array, though.

Comment: That returns the object itself though, not its index.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].name.indexOf("Autauga, AL") > -1) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's what the OP is referring to as "brute force loops".

Answer (score 0):

You could write a small function to do the job based on [*Array.prototype.some*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.17):

```
function getIndex(arr, prop, value) {
  var idx;
  arr.some(function(v, i) {
    if (v[prop] == value) {
      idx = i;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return idx;
}

data = [{"name": "Autauga, AL","value": 5.6},
        {"name": "Baldwin, AL","value": 5.3}];

console.log(getIndex(data, 'name', 'Baldwin, AL'));  // 1
```

*some* is efficient because it stops when the callback first returns true. You may wisht to adjust the condition to suit.

Comment: Shouldn't your `some` callback function return `true` instead of `false` when finding a match?  It looks like you wrote it for `every` instead..

Comment: Oh yes, oops!!! Still "works" with false, it just traverses the entire array and *idx* will be the last match, not the first.